# iPad mini Retina can no longer access shared reminders

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, reminders

My wife and I both have iPhone SEs, and iPad minis (original Retina version).  Our phones are updated to the latest iOS 14 version, but the mini cannot go past 12.x.  This means the minis are no longer able to see shared reminders *at all*.  We use(d) these all the time in the past, and have quite a few shared reminders lists between us.  This has rendered our iPads essentially useless for this application.

From what I'm reading, there is no actual solution here, it's as designed by Apple and basically they would expect us to toss the old hardware and buy something newer.  Given that this is an unacceptable "solution" in my eyes...

Are there any 3rd party list-sharing-capable apps that will work on iOS 12.x, iOS 14.x, and macOSes as far back as Sierra (we also have some old macs that can't update further but are otherwise perfectly suited to our needs)?

EDIT:  To add to this, I just realized that even our iPhones can no longer access shared reminders!  Nor can my MBP I just updated to Catalina.  WTF!?  How can we get our shared reminders/lists back again??

Comment: Can any of the older devices still access the reminders that were shared in the past?

Comment: @JamesBrickley Not shared reminders, no. That’s the thrust of this post.

Comment: Pretty sure it was iOS13 and above that triggered the problem - https://www.imore.com/should-you-update-reminders-app-across-your-iphone-ipad-and-mac

Comment: Obviously, that does not help you... Other than to explain what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an incompatibility between reminder lists before and after iOS 13 / iPadOS 13.

> If you upgrade your account in the Reminders app on a device with iOS 13, iPadOS 13, macOS 10.15, or later, you see upgraded reminders on iCloud.com. To see which version of Reminders you have, look for one of the following:
>
> If you’re using upgraded reminders, you see the More button at the top-right corner of each reminder list.
>
> If you’re not using upgraded reminders, you see Options at the top-right corner of each reminder list.
>
> Once you upgrade, you can view your reminders on iCloud.com and on your devices with iOS 13, iPadOS 13, macOS 10.15, or later that are signed in with the same Apple ID. **If you also have devices with earlier versions of iOS or macOS, you don’t see your upgraded reminders on those devices.**

https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/aside/mm598466a1d9/1.0/icloud/1.0

Comment: But here's the thing... I don't see EITHER of those things.  On my iPhone (iOS14), I see an elipsis (3 dots menu).  On macOS, I have a Plus sign (which creates a new item).  Additionally, I can't even see those shared lists *on the iPhone itself*.  They just have the yellow triangle with exclamation point.  And on my Mac running Catalina, I just get the "The creator of this list has upgraded these reminders." message.  I'm sure I'm running the "upgraded" reminders on my phone, I remember the warning but didn't fully understand the impact of it then. Also I get the same message at iCloud.com.

Comment: Can you post screenshots? I think what you called "an elipsis (3 dots menu)" is what that second paragraph I quoted is referring to as "the More button" (but im not sure)

Comment: Sure thing…  https://snipboard.io/vyfacr.jpg